# Vim mapping acts different when switching between Mac OS X/Linux

Tags: vim, gvim, gvimrc

I've been working with Vim on two different machines, one running Ubuntu 10.04 (gVim) and the other Snow Leopard (MacVim). I copied my .vimrc file and .vim folder to both, and noticed a few minor differences. 2 questions:

1 . I used Drew Neil's [vimcast on indentation](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/indentation-commands/) and added the following to my .vimrc:

```
nmap <D-[> <<
nmap <D-]> >>
vmap <D-[> <gv
vmap <D-]> >gv
```

Which maps `Cmd+[` and `Cmd+]` to indent in/out. In Linux I replaced '**D**' with '**C**', so that it works with `Ctrl+[` / `]`. All of that works on both machines, only that on Linux, hitting the Escape key after indenting performs an un-indent action. Any thoughts?

2 . I added some script I found to my .vimrc that enables shifting rows (normal and visual mode) up/down by holding Ctrl and using the up/down keys. It works great on Linux, but doesn't work at all on Mac, and I can't understand why. [See my .vimrc file here](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/251527/).

Comment: can you formulate it as one or two questions?

Comment: On your Linux system, are you using Vim in GUI-mode or in tty-mode (i.e. through a terminal program like xterm, rxvt, Gnome Terminal, et cetera)? Your problem likely is due to the fact that Escape and Control-[ share the same character representation (ASCII 27) and are indistinguishable in a tty-based environment. The GUI version of Vim should be able to distinguish Escape from Control-[, but it may choose not to.

Comment: I use the gui version on both linux and mac (gnome-vim and macvim). Perhaps I'll map it to another key (Ctrl+T / Ctrl+Shift+T).